# SqlDependency.Start не работает в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я создаю простое клиент-серверное приложение и застрял на взаимодействии с SQL.
Если я в "обычной" вижуал студии запускаю код:

```
using System.Data;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         SqlDependency.Start("server=111.111.111.111;database=db;Persist Security Info=false;Integrated Security=false;User Id=user;Password=password");
    }
}
```

То я вижу все правильно созданные службы в Service Broker'e в SQL студии.

Но стоит мне запустить нечто похожее из юнитей:

```
using System.Data;
public class ABC : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void Start()
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.Start("server=111.111.111.111;database=db;Persist Security Info=false;Integrated Security=false;User Id=user;Password=password")
    }
}
```

То код просто не отрабатывает. Никаких ошибок, просто ничего. Пробовал подключать разные версии System.Data - не помогло.

```
bool a=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.Start("server=111.111.111.111;database=db;Persist Security Info=false;Integrated Security=false;User Id=user;Password=password")
Debug.Log(a)
```

возвращает True

Прошу о помощи.

Answer (score 2):

После двух дней поисков решения я его таки нашел.

Идем в Edit > Project Settings > Player, далее меняем "Scripting Runtime Version" на".NET 4.x Equivalent" и"Api Compatibility Level" на".NET 4x", перезапускаем юнити. Идем в Unity\Editor\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\lib\mono\4.5 и копируем System.Data.dll в папку своего проекта.

И тогда она работает. Надеюсь кому-нибудь поможет.